# Using SQL Server Profiler to track performance for nested stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, profiler

I have a slow unit test (defined as a SQL script) executing stored procedures nested in other stored procdedures.
I'd like to know if SQL Server Profiler provides tracks for execution along the 'call stack' at different nesting levels.

Comment: Profiler is old way and is very resource intensive and will screw your numbers. A much better way is to use extended events or server side trace.

Comment: more complicated I guess ?

Comment: more complicated I guess ? For relative profiling that is still a good tool. I could find the bottle neck and dig in. That was a question more design oriented as matter of fact rather admin oriented, but when it comes to performance I was sure this community could help as you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer in the meantime - sorry for the inconvenience

in profiler settings it is possible to select all events from there a list is provided and some settings can be checked to tracks for SP execution

Comment: Also, please add the particular settings to be checked so this is a complete answer for others.